# Stack Overflow is no longer listed in the Stack Exchange reputation graph

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, reputation-graph

When I try to open the reputation graph in StackExchange the following message appears:

```
Accounts must have a minimum of 200 reputation to appear in this graph
```

My StackOverflow account has more than 200, so it should appear in the graph, as it used to.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GAg0.jpg]

Comment: Interesting - I don't see Stack Overflow in my graph either and I definitely have more than 200 rep over there!

Comment: Same here. Maybe a glitch in combination with caching resulting from the rep-recalc.

Comment: @gnat Nice drawings! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to do a massive backfill of that data after the global recalcs...a plan is in place and should be completed today if all goes well.

Comment: It's working now.